# How to make calculating the inverse matrix more robust?

Tags: c++, mathematics, matrix, floating-point

When I calculated the inverse matrix, I found that the error in using the float data type would cause the inverse matrix calculation error. Is there any good solution?

```c
    template<unsigned int Row, unsigned int Col, typename T>
inline bool inverse(const MATRIX<Row, Col, T>& matrix, MATRIX<Row, Col, T>& out) {

    if (Row != Col)
        return false;

    MATRIX<Row, Col * 2, T> augmentedMatrix;

    for (int i = 0; i < Row; i++) 
        for (int j = 0; j < Col; j++) {
            augmentedMatrix(i, j) = matrix(i, j);
            
            if (i == j) 
                augmentedMatrix(i, j + matrix.GetNumOfRow()) = 1.0;
            else
                augmentedMatrix(i, j + matrix.GetNumOfRow()) = 0.0;
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetNumOfRow(); i++) {
        int pivotRow = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < matrix.GetNumOfRow(); j++)
            if (augmentedMatrix(j, i) > augmentedMatrix(pivotRow, i))
                pivotRow = j;

        for (int k = 0; k < 2 * matrix.GetNumOfRow(); k++) {
            T tmp = augmentedMatrix(i, k);
            augmentedMatrix(i, k) = augmentedMatrix(pivotRow, k);
            augmentedMatrix(pivotRow, k) = tmp;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetNumOfRow(); j++)
            if (j != i) {
                T ratio;
                if (augmentedMatrix(i, i) != 0.0)
                    ratio = augmentedMatrix(j, i) / augmentedMatrix(i, i);
                else
                    return false;

                for (int k = 0; k < 2 * matrix.GetNumOfRow(); k++)
                    augmentedMatrix(j, k) -= ratio * augmentedMatrix(i, k);
            }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetNumOfRow(); i++) {
        T diagonalElement = augmentedMatrix(i, i);
        for (int j = 0; j < 2 * matrix.GetNumOfRow(); j++)
            augmentedMatrix(i, j) /= diagonalElement;

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetNumOfRow(); i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetNumOfCol(); j++)
            out(i, j) = augmentedMatrix(i, j + matrix.GetNumOfRow());

    return true;
}
```

The following is the test data：
"A" is the matrix that needs to be inverted,
"_invA" is the inverse matrix of A,
"A * _invA" is not equal to the identity matrix.

```c
A:
0.000126122162   0.000103404600   8.10868223e-05
0.000103404600   0.000123339385   0.000142923338
8.10868223e-05   0.000142923323   0.000203671603
_invA
6.69108429e+10    -1.35020265e+11   6.81094472e+10
-1.35020265e+11   2.72459219e+11    -1.37438986e+11
6.81094308e+10    -1.37438953e+11   6.93295350e+10
A * invA
0.500000000       0.00000000     -0.500000000
-1.00000000       2.00000000      -1.00000000
-1.00000000       0.00000000       0.00000000
```

Comment: The term for how robust an algorithm is against accumulating error with finite precision is "numerical stability". Searching with this and related keywords may help find useful references here. For example, [this StackOverflow post is specific to 2x2 matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8690456/3064164), but some techniques discussed in the answers may generalize to higher dimensions.

Comment: That matrix `A` is scaling down some 100,000times. Way to much for floats. Consider scaling up the  values you apply `A` to so that `A` need not be so tiny. Or use doubles.